# has_secure_password (bcrypt) makes all tests slower in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I am following Michael Hartl's [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up). It says to reduce bcrypt cost in tests I should add to `config/environments/test.rb` the following

```
require 'bcrypt'
silence_warnings do
  BCrypt::Engine::DEFAULT_COST = BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST
end
```

I did this and it speed up all tests (as measured by watching the green dots appear) even if they seem to have nothing to do with testing the user database model. Can anyone verify this and/or explain why I am seeing this?

Comment: Perhaps it's used to encrypt passwords when loading a `users` table, via fixtures or factories. The tables are cleaned and reloaded on each test.

Answer (score 2):

Bcrypt is very slow. The performance will increase by the computational expense parameter.

Hence, lower the paramater will speed up bcrypt calculation a lot.

The reason to use bcrypt is because it's slow. Hence, it will take much longer to brute force encrypted password.